# HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403, https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?

Tags: flutter, dart

Good morning all, i am getting this error when i click on "Current Location" on my emulator screen

```
     EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403,
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
```

center=&37.4219983,-122.084&zoom=16&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C37.4219983,-122.084&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:100

#1      NetworkImage.load
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:51
#2      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:505
#3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent
package:flutter/…/painting/image_cache.dart:360
#4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:503
#5      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:108
#6      ImageProvider.resolve.
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:334
#7      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey..
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:464
#8      SynchronousFuture.then
package:flutter/…/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:43
#9      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:461
#13     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:453
#14     ImageProvider.resolve
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:331
#15     _ImageState._resolveImage
package:flutter/…/widgets/image.dart:1116
#16     _ImageState.didChangeDependencies
package:flutter/…/widgets/image.dart:1069
#17     StatefulElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4705
#18     ComponentElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4520
#19     Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3490
#20     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3255
#21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5881
#22     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3245
#23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5881
#24     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3245
#25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5881
#26     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3245
#27     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5881
#28     Element.updateChild

This is my "LocationHelper" code

```
const GOOGLE_API_KEY = "I entered my API KEY here";



class LocationHelper {
  static String generateLocationPreviewImage({double latitude, double longitude}) {
    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&$latitude,$longitude&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C$latitude,$longitude&key=$GOOGLE_API_KEY";
  }
}
```

And here is where i use it

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

import '../helpers/location_helper.dart';

class LocationInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationInputState createState() => _LocationInputState();
}

class _LocationInputState extends State<LocationInput> {
  String _previewImageUrl;

  Future<void> _getCurrentUserLocation () async {
    final locData = await Location().getLocation();
   final staticMapImageUrl = LocationHelper.generateLocationPreviewImage(
     latitude: locData.latitude,
     longitude: locData.longitude,
   );
   setState(() {
     _previewImageUrl = staticMapImageUrl;
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          child: _previewImageUrl == null
              ? Text(
                  "No location found",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                )
              : Image.network(_previewImageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover, width: double.infinity),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
              label: Text(
                "Current Location",
              ),
              textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
              onPressed: _getCurrentUserLocation ,
            ),
            FlatButton.icon(
              label: Text(
                "Select on Map",
              ),
              textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              icon: Icon(Icons.map),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, i finally figured out that i did not enable "Maps Static API". it's ok now

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error 403 indicates authentication issues. See if Google static maps is enabled in the console. Otherwise, it's likely that you're using an incorrect API key.